# How to give a color to each x value in a 3D scatterplot in R

Tags: r, colors, scatter-plot

I need to analyze together 3 sets of data. I'm using `scatterplot3d` to analyze those data.
I need to give a different color to each of the values on the x axis.

```
The value on the x axis is Terreno (Soil) and goes from -4 to +6.
The value on the y axis is P.I.
The value on the z axis is PERSE.TOTALI (Total lost).
```

I'm able to create the 3D scatterplot but I'm not able to give a color to each value in the x axis, how should I proceed?
    Thanks

```
    #here are the data I'm trying to plot

    dput(head(dati3,25))
    structure(list(Terreno = c(-4L, -4L, -4L, 5L, -4L, 3L, 6L, -4L,
    5L, -4L, 3L, -4L, 5L, 3L, 5L, -4L, -4L, 3L, -4L, 3L, 3L, -4L,
    -4L, -4L, 3L), P.I. = c(1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1.5, 2, 1.5,
    1, 2, 1.5, 1, 0, 0, -0.5, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), PERSE.TOTALI = c(0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 25L), class = "data.frame")



    #this is the code I'm using for the plot

    scatterplot3d(Terreno, P.I., PERSE.TOTALI,pch=16,highlight.3d = T, type="h")
```

What should I insert in the code to have each of the x values plotted in a different color?
    Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

when you put `highlight.3d` to true, color is automatic and you can't change it. although if you are willing to use colors different by x, you can use the following code:

```
scatterplot3d(Terreno, P.I., PERSE.TOTALI, pch= 16, type= "h",
              color= as.numeric(as.factor(x)))
```

`color` can take as an argument any vector of the same length of data, and different values of that vector will give different colors for data points, so in the code above values of that vector come from vector x and are equal for equal x. if you decide a different palette of colours, you can use a code like this:

```
color= palette[as.numeric(as.factor(x)))]
```

or maybe just:

```
color= palette[x+5]
```